# How can a cleric overcome non-invisible stealth?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, stealth

Im a 11th level cleric and 5th tier mythic. We just had a session where the whole party got shut down hard because the single enemy was stealthing and we just could not kill the thing.

How can we deal with something that is sniping us invisibly? Whenever we put up defenses to protect ourselves it stops attacking. It also seems able to teleport somehow, we suspect there is some kind of limit on that ability, but we dont know.

We already know that its not invisible as I had invisibility purge up and it filled the whole room. The room in question was dim light. Which we think had a large part to do with it as there are lots of things that dim light aids.

So what suggestions can you give for increasing our perception or negating the stealth when its not based on invisibility?

Comment: Some invisibility, like that of the invisible stalker, is not subject to invisibility purge.

Comment: If you suspect that it's teleporting, another possible option might be to use spells that limit or stop teleportation effects, and see if that makes it easier to pin down.  It might not help though - if you've literally never seen this thing, it's always possible that there's more than one of them.

Comment: I know of dimensional anchor, but its a ray which means I need to target the thing first, which if we could do that the problem would be solved.

Comment: I'm not sure we can usefully answer a question that is basically "We don't know what's attacking us or how it's staying unseen; how do I defeat its unknown stealth power?"

Comment: Odd, thats how "combat" last night felt

Comment: This sounds like tunnel vision -- you think you know what's going on and are spending lots of effort to deal with it, but the reality is something else entirely.

Answer (score 3):

According to the Stealth skill rules on page 106

> It's impossible to use Stealth while attacking, running, or charging.

If he attacked you, then he lost his stealth. If he was 10' or more away from all of the PCs, then he could use the Sniping subsection to immediately try to Stealth again, but at a -20 penalty.

The two obvious ways to counter this are to spread out so he's within 10' of at least one person, or to simply wait for the huge -20 to catch him out. Any bonus to Wisdom or Perception should help with that.

Clerics have a number of spells that may or may not be beneficial. Here are some suggestions.

- Guidance (0): +1 to Perception if you've nothing better to do
- Detect Magic (0): in case he's carrying anything good
- Summon Monster (varies): phone a friend
- Detect Chaos/Evil/Good/Law (1): conditional, and takes time
- Owl's Wisdom (2): bonus to Perception
- Daylight: if dim lighting is the problem

The most obvious way that comes to mind at that level is to cast the spells Faerie Fire or Glitterdust (hat tip @Fering), which are not on the Cleric list.

Comment: Glitterdust would work better, and again not a cleric spell. They were snipping, and since the room was large enough, we could not effectively spread out to capture them, and since their "movement" appears to be teleportation based, we cant hear them move past.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Made me take a deeper look at the spells available.

Comment: You should note that summon monster 4 can get a salt mephit and they can cast glitterdust (and at level 5 a d3 of them)

Comment: I have a constant arcane sight up so I can literally see magical auras. However the entire dungeon is one big mythic anti-magic field which only affects divination magic. So cant see magic, and my tongues spell doesnt work. So I cant communicate with the vast majority of my summons so I cant tell them to use their spells, they can only attack.

Comment: @Fering: I admit I don't know the rules for summons, but I would imagine that a creature with an anti-stealth skill would use it if being attacked by something it can't see.